# naming division id anything I want

Tags: html, css, text-styling

Sorry for such a basic question.
when writing different div elements to later ID and style in css, can I name them whatever I want?

```
<div id="middle"></div>

<div id="yellow box"></div>

<div id="my dog"></div>

<div id="the green hornet"></div>
```

thanks.
p

Comment: example? Please edit your post

Comment: Yes but  avoid space between word in tag.. use camelCase o _underscore notation ed yellowBox  or yellow-box or  yellow_box

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use whatever ID you can come up with.

**In JavaScript**

This used to be a limitation when you wanted to access elements via their ID in *some* old browsers (Internet Explorer 5-6), that added functionality to access elements with an ID, for example:

```
document.all.middle // worked
document.all.yellow box // did not work (of course)
```

This behavior was only supported by Internet explorer however, and **should not be used**. Use something like this to access an element in JavaScript instead:

```
document.getElementById('my dog').textContent = 'Hello';
document.getElementById('the green hornet') = 'World';
```

**In CSS**

You need to escape spaces in CSS:

```
div#my weird spaced id {
  /* does not work */
}
```

```
div#my\ weird\ spaced\ id {
  /* works */
}
```

This does not work for classes however:

```
<div class="a b c">color me!</div>
```

```
div.a\ b\ c { color: red } /* does not work */
```

For classes, `a b c` means "class a and class b and class c". If you really really have to use them this way, you can style them via dot notation:

```
`div.a.b.c { color: red } /* works */
```

The *best practice* is to name them dash-separated, e.g. `my-fancy-class`, `main-nav-header`, etc.
If you prefer camelCase or underscore_notation, you can use them too, but dash-seprarated is more widespread.

Comment: downvoter care to elaborate what I can improve in my answer?